# Lebesgue point definition

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

A point $x_0 \in \Omega \subseteq \mathbb R^n$ (where $\Omega$ is open) is a Lebesgue point for $f : \Omega \rightarrow \mathbb R$ if
$$ \lim_{r \rightarrow 0} \dfrac{1}{\lambda (B(x_0,r))} \int_{B(x_0,r)} | f(t) - f(x_0)| \ dt = 0.$$
It is immediate to prove that from this definition it follows that
$$ \lim_{r \rightarrow 0} \dfrac{1}{\lambda (B(x_0,r))} \int_{B(x_0,r)} f(t) \  dt = f(x_0).$$
Is the converse true?

Comment: No, it isn't. (Look for a counterexample.) If it were, that would probably be the definition, since it's easier.

Comment: A hint for a counterexample?

Comment: Jump discontinuity.

Comment: Obviously the sign function in $0$, thank you.